# Select box placeholder option select default in value empty string or undefined or null

Tags: angular, select-options

I want to page rendering time select the placeholder option in that select box value `empty string` or `undefined` or `null`

[My sample angular code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-49cxm2)

It's worked only one value(`empty string`).

But I want the above three value(`empty string` or `undefined` or `null`)

My requirement solution for my guess is values with Or-symbol in option.

For ex:

```
<option [value]="''||undefined||null" disabled selected>Select Product</option>
```

But it does not work. If anybody knows that solution share with me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[value]` cannot accept a logical expression. Simply, assign the value `''` to the model when you see that the model is `null` or `undefined`:

```
this.item.genericByProd = this.item.genericByProd || '';
```